# Error: Final local variable score cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use the getIntent value(score) which is retrieve from the previous activity but it seems like it is impossible. It seems that addition and subtraction under if else cannot detect score. Is there any other way?

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import com.mkyong.android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup radioAnswerGroup2;
    private RadioButton radioAnswerButton2;
    private Button btnSubmit2;

    Button button2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        addListenerOnButton();


    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        radioAnswerGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswer2);


        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button2pre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2pre);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final int score = intent.getIntExtra("int", -1);
        final TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult2);
        result2.setText("Result counting: " + String.valueOf(score));


        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                int correctId2 = (R.id.answer2b);

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId2 = radioAnswerGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radio button by returned id
                radioAnswerButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId2);

                if (selectedId2==correctId2){

                     score = score + 1;
                    //show toast saying it is correct
                    //Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    //CharSequence text = ("You are correct!");
                    //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    //toast.show();
                }
                else{

                    score = score - 1;
                    //toast incorrect
                    //Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    //CharSequence text = ("You are wrong but it's ok and the answer is Data Link");
                    //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                    //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    //toast.show();
                }   

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(App2Activity.this, App3Activity.class);
                intent2.putExtra("int", score); 
                startActivity(intent2);  

            }

        });


        button2pre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move `int score` to be a global variable to access it in onClick.  You'll also need to remove the `final` keyword so the value can be changed after you initialize it.

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity{

       int score;

      public onCreate( /*...etc.*/
```

Comment: omg! it work :D now i get it. you are my saviour and thank you sooo much

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `final` keyword from :

```
final int score = intent.getIntExtra("int", -1);
```

Because a `final` variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_variables).

Comment: Hello Kazekage Gara thank u so much for reply. I did that but the error is still there and when i highlight the error the software give me quick fix to put in final

Comment: Make it a global variable then as suggested by the other answer. And never make a variable `final` if you want to make changes to it later on. The error that you are talking about, you are using Eclipse? Statements that are underlined in yellow can be ignored, they are warnings,not errors.